# How to do partial text search in Cloudsearch

Tags: search, solr, lucene, full-text-search, amazon-cloudsearch

I have an indexed field of type "text" called obj_title in cloudsearch.  It's value is

```
queryevents@abc.com
```

If I search for `ts` or `*ts*` or `events` or `*events*`. I get no results. I get results if I search for string `queryevents` though.

I have tried Simple/Lucene/DisMax query parsers. What do I need to change in order to support Cloudsearch returning results on  `ts` or `*ts*` or `events` or `*events*`

I don't see option to have `NgramFilter` or `EdgeNgramTokenizer` field type in Cloudsearch. What am I missing?

Comment: you need to change the fieldType for your like use NgramFilter or EdgeNgramTokenizer. Chnage the same in your schema file for your field. Once done the changes re-index the data with it

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti Those are not the optons for fieldType in CloudSearch unfortunately. I see "literal, text, text-array, latlon, int-array, double, double-array, int, literal-array, date, date-array"

Comment: @AbhijitBashetti https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/configuring-index-fields.html

Comment: literal seems same as the String type of solr. You can try that. Only issue would be here Literal fields are case-sensitive.

Comment: I'm not sure if CloudSearch supports postfix/infix searches, only prefix searches are mentioned at their text search page: https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cloudsearch/latest/developerguide/searching-text.html